# How to return a summary of distinct values held within CouchDB

Tags: couchdb

Given a collection of objects held within CouchDB that look like this:

```
{
   "_id": "-5739365454",
   "_rev": "1-d55b2651b214113bab0b4c18a401eaef",
   "userId": "mike",
   "remoteAddr": "77.102.112.205"
}

{
   "_id": "-573936626",
   "_rev": "1-778bbf1c0e5cfe8bbd83dbe618e8b549",
   "userId": "mike",
   "remoteAddr": "77.102.112.205"
}
...
{
   "_id": "-573954545",
   "_rev": "1-4350856f40c091156f8bb984a5559ebd",
   "userId": "jeff",
   "remoteAddr": "77.102.112.205"
}
```

I wish to create an output view that give me a set of results that looks something like the following (pseudo output - not syntactically valid):

```
userId     count
mike       2
jeff       1
...
```

So, one 'row'/element would exist in the output for each distinct userId in the DB, along with the number of times that userId exists in the DB.

So far I have the following:

```
{
   "_id": "_design/myObj",
   "_rev": "4-cd468634f4fb6bef500753fedcb35e27",
   "views": {
       "by_userId": {
           "map": "function(doc) { if (doc.userId) { emit (doc.userId, doc._id)} }",
           "reduce": "_stats"
       }
   },
   "language": "javascript"
}
```

... but this is not working as required. Any assistance gratefully received!

Comment: The three documents in your example all have the same `_id` and `_rev` values.  Is this just a copy and paste error?

Comment: Yes, just a paste error while I simulated the example for the purposes of this question. Let me correct that .

Comment: oh, and what result did you get when running the view?

Comment: The view is not working at all it seems

Comment: There is no output at all?  Can you access the couchdb log files?

Comment: You should use `_count` instead of `_stats` if you want it to match your example.

Comment: This looks as if it's just returning the overall count of objects in my DB: {"rows":[
{"key":null,"value":29}
]} - rather than each discrete userId and the number of objects which contain that userId

Answer (score 0):

You could try use _count built-in function. For instance:

```
`
{
    "_id": "_design/myObj",
    "_rev": "4-cd468634f4fb6bef500753fedcb35e27",
    "views": {
        "by_userId": {
            "map": "function(doc) { if (doc.userId) { emit (doc.userId, null)} }",
           "reduce": "_count"
       }
   },
   "language": "javascript"
}`
```

Comment: This is returning just the overall count of objects in the DB: {"rows":[
{"key":null,"value":29}
]}

Comment: Are you using the Futon interface (couchdb:5984/_utils)? Maybe you are forgetting to check 'reduce' field on interface. I've did that a lot.

Comment: No, I'm querying the DB using the view from the design directly over HTTP. If I were missing the reduce function I would anticipate getting a list of objects back, keyed on the userId. However, I'm getting a count of all the objects in the DB which have a userId property, suggesting to me the reduce function is being taken into account.